# Facebook Graph Get User Life events

Tags: javascript, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I have a doubt about, how to get the user life events using the facebook graph API.

For example to get the feed timeline i do this HTTP Call.

```
var urlToTimeline = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/posts?access_token=" + user.services.facebook.accessToken
    HTTP.get(urlToTimeline, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    })
```

And this work, but now im tryin to figure out how the url request should look to get the [life events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/life-event) 
BTW im Using the Meteor Framework.

Comment: What you linked to is about an object called life event, but it seems to be for page milestones actually. Pretty sure you can not get a user’s life events via API.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Meteor you should consider installing a facebook sdk package such as [biasport:facebook-sdk](https://atmospherejs.com/biasport/facebook-sdk) so that you can use the fb sdk directly. Then according to the fb documentation you just access life events by id:

```
FB.api(
    "/{life-event-id}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: Now im getting struggle where i get this life events